# Java ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of List?

Tags: java, list, concurrency, thread-safety, queue

I have a worker thread which should iterate over an `ArrayList<ConcurrentLinkedQueue>`. Other threads can add and remove objects (queues). But ArrayList is not thread-safe. Would it be fine to use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ConcurrentLinkedQueue>` instead of `ArrayList<ConcurrentLinkedQueue>`?

Comment: `List` is an interface. Some implementations are thread-safe (e.g. `CopyOnWriteArrayList`), others are not (e.g. `ArrayList`).

Comment: What would be the difference? Why would ConcurrentLinkedQueue not work or why is it bad?

Comment: I think it depends on what you need to do. I'd give more details about your requirements.

Comment: Basically all what I am doing is said in the question. There is a thread which keeps iterating over the List and other threads can add and remove objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking if you can iterate a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` safely, then the answer is Yes.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) says:

> `Iterators` are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the queue at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. **They do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and may proceed concurrently with other operations.** Elements contained in the queue since the creation of the iterator will be returned exactly once.

However, there are things that you can do on a `List` that you cannot do on a `Queue` (e.g. positional get / set, insertion / removal of arbitrary elements.)  If your application needs to do those things or similar, then using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of `ArrayList` won't work.

Also, beware that `ConcurrentLinkedQueue.size()` is an `O(N)` operation!